# Boot Camp missing Coprocessor, SMBus Controller Drivers

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, driver

I installed Windows 7 on a user's Macbook Pro yesterday (Aug 2010 model I believe) using Boot Camp, then I used the Mac OS X disc to run the Boot Camp Drivers installation.  I then restarted as normal and went about the myriad other installs, when I entered devices and noticed the "!" symbol on the computer.

Lo and behold, 3 drivers were missing: Coprocessor, SMBus, and a third that I can't recall at the moment.  I found several references to the missing Coprocessor and SMBus online, but the posted solutions (to install nVidia drivers, to run the Intel Update service, to let Windows 7 try to find the drivers itself) all failed (some of the driver installations reported the incorrect hardware, some installed but didn't resolve the missing drivers in Devmgmt).

I've installed Windows 7 on 10+ Macbook Pros and never once run into missing drivers after installing the boot camp driver pack.  Everything seems to be working fine: display, ethernet and wireless, sound, track pad, eject button all function perfectly, but the ! in Device Manager are driving me crazy.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried repairing or reinstalling with the install discs?

Comment: I haven't them yet but there's some solutions on here http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/coprocessor-and-sm-bus-controller-drivers-for-windows-7-32bit-issue.634282/

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue by using the latest drivers from Apple. If not resolved using the latest update try installing the missing drivers manually and locate the folder where the Apple drivers are put. Hope it helps.

Cheers.